# Get entries by custom Users field value

Tags: users, elementcriteriamodel

There is a set of entries:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('news') %}
```

Each entry has a custom field `customUserField`.  `customUserField` this is a field Users. How do you fetch entries where `customUserField` === `currentUser`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('news').relatedTo({
    targetElement: currentUser,
    field: 'customUserField'
}).find() %}
```

More on the relatedTo method here: https://craftcms.com/docs/relations